# Whats the command line for copy and paste in termimal?

Tags: command-line, scripts, shortcut-keys, .desktop

So here is what I am trying to do, questions will be at the end.
I'm being very pedantic I know, but its a good learning experience and a good bit of fun.

I am creating a setup script, which includes all the repositories and apts/snap packages i will need for a fresh setup, along with some CHMOD/CHOWN settings.

---

So in my script file I can just use **$USER**  *e.g.* /media/**$USER**/blah blah, that works.
But, in my setup.desktop shortcut I need to use the actual username instead of **$USER**.

How can I run a script to; pull the current username, copy that user name, edit the .desktop file then paste the name into the EXEC= /media/**USERNAME**/ path?

---

To break down the questions as I know there are multiple in that one.
How can I copy a text from terminal, WITHOUT using mouse or keyboard?

Is there a -[CRTL + C] entry I can type e.g. -x is execute in CHMOD, instead of using my keyboard to press the CTRL SHFT C key?

If so, what is both copy and paste?

OR is there an easier way to put the username into the shortcut file via a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, replace "USERNAME" with "$USER"-content...

```
$ echo >TEMP.desktop "EXEC=/media/USERNAME/someexecfile"

$ sed -ire "s/USERNAME/$USER/" TEMP.desktop 

$ cat TEMP.desktop 
EXEC=/media/hannu/someexecfile
```

**Related:**
*[www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) > Bash guides - will tell a lot of detail about how to use Bash and write Bash scripts, already by skimming through them (there are two guides)*

`$ man sed` will tell you details about `sed` in particular,
https://regex101.com/ - contains a test-bench for regular expressions.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/ - tutorials and examples on regex'es.

---

`$ man xclip` for setting / accessing actual clipboard data. note that a clipboard might be application-local, e.g. an application might not be using the X clipboard.

Comment: Absolute legend!